# bootstrap popover doesn't showing any link on popover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, popover

i m using the bootstrap popover in my wordpress site and its working well.but i want that in my popover i want to show 4 links but it doesn't showing any link instead of that its removing my image from where i want to open popover.

Here is my code for popover:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span2"><a data-original-title="Create" data-placement="top" rel="popover" data-html="true" data-content="<a>Hello</a> |<a>Hello</a> |<a>Hello</a> |<a>Hello</a> "><img src="http://placehold.it/170x170" class="img-circle" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my java script:

```
<script>
$('[rel="popover"]').popover();
</script>
```

Comment: Help me guys need ur help....:(

Comment: This code by itself works. There must be something else on the page breaking it. Start by checking your browser's console for errors and post them if there are any. Some more of the page's code would be helpful too, or a live demo of it.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a diffecnce but try putting in a blank href on your inital 'a'a tag as they have one present on the Bootstrap docs page.

Comment: @frostyterrier: i found the eror as:

ReferenceError: auto is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

but unable to find it coz after clicking on it it showsthe error is on:

<script type='text/javascript'>
Galleria.configure({
debug : false, // debug is now off for deployment
imageCrop : true,
thumbCrop : true,
carousel : true,
thumbnails : true,
transition : 'fade',
transitionSpeed : 400,
thumbEventType : 'click',
autoplay : true,
clicknext : true,
showImagenav : true,
showCounter : true,
lightbox : true,
imagePan : false,
width : auto,

}); 

width   : auto,

Comment: Thanks, that's what we needed. I have posted an answer that should fix  that error (and the popover). If that doesn't fix it or any other errors pop up you will need to post those as well. You can reply to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling in at document ready. Also, WordPress uses `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Try this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('[rel="popover"]').popover();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
Galleria.configure({ debug : false, // debug is now off for deployment
    ...
    showCounter : true,
    lightbox : true,
    imagePan : false, 
    width : auto,
}); width   : auto,
```

The error you are getting says "auto is not defined" and you have a stray **width   : auto,** after the closing brackets }); I suspect that's the problem. Remove that **width   : auto,**

*I posted the snippet above to show you where it is but I removed part of the code so don't replace your code with what I posted. Just remove the **width   : auto,**